# How can I include hypen in my regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string: `FOO_KEK_-150915`

My current regex that is not working: `FOO_([A-Z_])-150915`

What is wrong with my regex, I'm trying to find files that starts with "FOO" and end with that number?

Comment: Why use regex? `s.StartsWith("FOO_") && s.EndsWith("-150915")`.

Comment: Because in real life it is more complicated :)

Comment: This is the worst feedback: "I have different input". Please, post real life example. Or are you trying to *extract* those names from a longer string?

Comment: BTW, both the answer are not precise. Please post the real-life input data and the expected results.

Comment: Ok, I will warn you that `FOO_([A-Z_]+)-150915` will also find a match in `BOOFOO_([A-Z_]+)-150915234556444`. Do you really want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[A-Z_]` matches exactly *one* character. So it would only match e.g. `FOO_K-150915` or even `FOO__-150915`.

In order to match multiple characters, you need to specify the quantity, for example using `+`:

```
FOO_([A-Z_]+)-150915
```

Comment: If the OP only wanted to _match_ the expression, which seems to be the case, you don't really need the parenthesis here.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOO_([A-Z_]+)-150915

          ^^
```

You need to add `quantifer` `*` or `+` or `{1,4}` or else it will match just `1` and your regex will fail.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/33